# Plugins - Install Local Copy: Unable to parse plugin.xml

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm having problems installing plugins with VS2015 Community + Cordova.  I followed the instructions to install custom local and I get the error:
`Visual Studio was unable to parse plugin.xml`[image]

Instructions to add local plugin copy: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-general-readme/#install-from-a-local-copy

I'm unable to install plugins with config.xml > Plugins > Core and I get the same error

Note: I recently update `Node` to v4.2.1.  Adding plugins has worked great in the past with no problems.

Any ideas on how to fix or work around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, but not sure where the problem originates.

I'm was using `Node v4.2.1` and `Cordova 5.3.1`

**Solution was to update to `Cordova 5.3.3`**

Failure to add plugin: 
[image]

Changing Cordova version number:
[image]

Success adding plugin:
[image]